# Improving success probability for one sided error algorithms

Tags: complexity-theory, randomized-algorithms

Suppose I have a probabilistic Turing machine for a language such that
$$ x \in A \implies \Pr(M \text{ accepts } x) \ge \frac{1}{n}$$
$$ x \notin A \implies \Pr(M \text{ accepts } x) = 0$$
I want to show that the above language is in $\mathsf{RP}$. In particular, I need a probabilistic Turing machine $N$ such that 
$$ x \in A \implies \Pr(N \text{ accepts } x) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$$ where $n = |x|$.

I tried to construct $N$ such that it runs $M$ multiple times (say $t$ times) and accepts if at least one of the runs accepts. This preserves the one-sided error but I'm not sure if it runs in polynomial time.

I showed that $x \in A \implies \Pr(N \text{ accepts } x) \ge 1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^t$.

Now, to show that it is in $\mathsf{RP}$,

$$1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^t \ge 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$ (1-\frac{1}{n})^t \le \frac{1}{2^n} $$

I am basically stuck at this point and unable to show an upper bound for $t$. I know that it suffices to show that $t$ is polynomial in $n$ but I am not able to prove it. How do I show that $N$ is indeed a polynomial time machine? Or maybe this is not the right approach?

Comment: Solve for t. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I tried doing that by taking log on both sides, but that is giving me a lower bound for t.

Comment: You don't need an upper bound on what t _suffice_, you just need an upper bound on what t are _necessary_. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Could you please expand on that? I don't understand.

Comment: For example, can you show that there exists a bounded x such that ​ ​ ​ x > 2 ​ ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks a lot. I think $t = n^3$ will work in this case since it satisfies the inequality and it is a polynomial.

Comment: You could also use a quadratic with a sufficiently-large coefficient. ​ ​